# Finding out if half the letters in a word are vowels

Tags: python, python-3.x

Like the title says, I'm trying to find out if vowels are at least half the amount of letters in a word.

Heres my code:

```
def mostlyVowels(words):
    vowel = 'aAeEiIoOuU'
    words.split()
    ans =  []
    for word in words:
        for letter in word:
            isvowel = 0
            if letter in vowel:
                isvowel += 1
        if isvowel > ((len(word))/2):
            ans.append(word)
    return ans

# call mostlyvowels
words = 'Our lives begin to end the day we become silent about things that matter'
print(mostlyVowels(words))
```

so what I should get is ['our', 'about'] But instead I get this:

```
['O', 'u', 'i', 'e', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'e', 'e', 'a', 'e', 'e', 'o', 'e', 'i', 'e', 'a', 'o', 'u', 'i', 'a', 'a', 'e']
```

thanks for taking the time to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would actually recommend doing this without using division, if just as an homage to the automata theory class I had to take to simulate using a tape to keep track of symbols:

```
def mostlyVowels(words):
  acc = []
  for word in words.split():
    i = 0
    for char in word.lower():
      if char in 'aeiou': i += 1
      else:               i -= 1
    if i > 0: acc.append(word)
  return acc
```

A non-vowel simply reduces the "mostly-vowelness" of a word, and the threshold is 1 or higher :P

Comment: Thats awesome, any reason why you would do it without division? It seemed pretty logical, but your method is so good.

Comment: Well, not really, I had imagined it to be slightly faster (I think most machine languages make single increments/decrements a quick operation, although I don't know this for a fact) but after initially replying, I realized division by 2 is also trivial in binary ;p  ...and I slightly prefer the clarity that comes from avoiding integer division (at least for me it seems more clear)

Comment: Yeah, I was surprised at the simplicity of this, nice job

Comment: I think Turing would approve of your use of increment/decrement rather than division. :) In Python, you could make it more compact (but a little obscure): `i += (-1, 1)[char in 'aeiou']`

Answer (score 3):

Your own code is resetting isvowel to zero for each letter in word, set `isvowel = 0`  before the second for loop not after or you can use sum to shorten your code:

```
def mostlyVowels(words):
    vowel = {"A","e","E","i","I","o","O","u","U"}
    final = []
    for word in words.split():
        if sum(x in vowel for x in word) >= len(word)/2:
            final.append(word)
    return final
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for fun, here's Darren Ringer's algorithm converted into a one-liner using a list (in)comprehension:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

def mostlyVowels(words):
    return [w for w in words.split() if sum((-1, 1)[c in 'aeiou'] for c in w.lower()) >= 0]


def main():
    words = 'Our lives begin to end the day we become silent about things that matter'
    print(mostlyVowels(words))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**output**

```
['Our', 'to', 'we', 'become', 'about']
```

I've modified the test so that it includes words with *at least* half the letters are vowels, as per the question.

Comment: Awesome, I have yet to really get into doing things the true 'pythonic' way as you have done... compact and clear, what high level languages are really for :D

Comment: Thanks, guys! :blush: @DarrenRinger Notice that I called it a list (in)comprehension. While it can be tempting to do clever stuff like this, make sure that it's not so clever that it's hard to read and understand. :) Never forget [Kernighan's Law](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Brian_Kernighan): "Everyone knows that debugging is twice as hard as writing a program in the first place. So if you're as clever as you can be when you write it, how will you ever debug it?"

Answer (score 2):

```
s = 'Our lives begin to end the day we become silent about things that matter'
words = s.split() # get whitespace-separated words
print([w for w in words if is_vowel_word(w)]) # result
```

where `is_vowel_word()` could be:

```
def is_vowel_word(word, vowels=set('aeiou')):
    """Whether half of the letters in a word are vowels."""
    letters = set(word.lower()) # count each distinct letter in the word once
    return len(vowels & letters) >= len(letters - vowels)
```

#### Output

```
['Our', 'to', 'we', 'about']
```

Or we count duplicate letters in the word too:

```
def is_vowel_word_dups(word, vowels='aeiou'):
    """Whether half of the letters (counting duplicates) in a word are vowels.

    """
    return 2*sum(c in vowels for c in word.lower()) >= len(word)
```

#### Output

```
['Our', 'to', 'we', 'become', 'about']
```

Note: the latter list has word `'become'` where `e` occurs twice: the word has `2` unique vowels ('eo') and `3` consonants ('bcm') that is why it is not included in the first list.

Here's a just for fun version that counts vowel *sounds* in a word instead of hardcoding `'aeiou'` letters:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from nltk.corpus import cmudict # $ pip install nltk
# $ python -c "import nltk; nltk.download('cmudict')"

def is_vowel_word_snd(word, pronunciations=cmudict.dict()):
    """Whether a word pronunciation contains at least half vowel *sounds*."""
    # check all pronuncations of the word
    return any(2*sum(syl[-1].isdigit() for syl in syllables) >= len(syllables)
               for syllables in pronunciations.get(word.lower(), []))

s = 'Our lives begin to end the day we become silent about things that matter'
words = s.split() # get whitespace-separated words
print([w for w in words if is_vowel_word_snd(w)])
```

#### Output

```
['Our', 'to', 'the', 'day', 'we', 'about', 'matter']
```

Answer (score 1):

`words.split()` does not modify the variable `words` in place - it simply returns a list, so you'll need to assign that to an intermediary variable. Or you can skip the middleman and call it right in your for-loop:

```
vowel = 'aAeEiIoOuU'
ans = []
for word in words.split():
    # etc.
```

Secondly, in your second for-loop, you are resetting `isvowel` to 0 every time, so it will never be greater than 1. You should move that assignment outside of the loop body:

```
    isvowel = 0
    for letter in word:
        if letter in vowel:
            isvowel += 1
    if isvowel > ((len(word))/2):
        ans.append(word)
    # etc.
```

Comment: Now it returns a list with all the words in the list, is that because isvowel doesnt get reset?

Comment: `isvowel = 0` should be inside the first for-loop body but outside the second for-loop body.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you need to split on the string Words. Otherwise, you're just iterating over every character in words :)

for word in words.split()

There might be something else to fix, let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Thanks for that, I still need to fix stuff though

Answer (score 0):

```
def mostly_vowels(words):
    vowels = set('aeiouAEIOU')
    for word in words.split():
        v = 0
        for char in word:
            if char in vowels:
                v += 1
        if v >= len(word)/2:
            print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some good answers out there that pointed to the problem. But, you can do that using List comprehension. Try to run this code:

```
vowel = 'aAeEiIoOuU'
words = 'Our lives begin to end the day we become silent about things that matter'
wordsList= words.split(" ")

l= [([x for x in item if x in list(vowel)], len(item), item) for item in  wordsList]
b= [y for y in l if (y[1]//2<len(y[0])) ]
print [z[2] for z in b]
```

Output: 
['Our', 'about']